# AngularJS $scope variable changing value for no reason?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an angular controller that get's data using the $http.get() method. I assign the response data to $scope.foo and also $scope.bar.

I then bind $scope.foo to an input field using ng-model="foo", and then a $scope function $scope.buttonClick to a button using ng-click="buttonClick()".

When I change the value of the input field and select the button, $scope.buttonClick outputs both $scope.foo and $scope.bar and they appear to match the newly entered value. This is odd because I only binded $scope.foo. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

controller:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('controller', ($scope, $http) => {

    $document.ready(() => {

        $http.get('/data').then((res) => {
            $scope.foo = res.data;
            $scope.bar = res.data;
        });

        $scope.buttonClick = () => console.log($scope.foo, $scope.bar);
    });
});
```

(Uses ES6 Syntax)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why and when to use angular.copy? (Deep Copy)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043850/why-and-when-to-use-angular-copy-deep-copy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$scope.foo and $scope.bar is pointing to the same property that is res.data. You must copy the objects:

`$scope.foo = angular.copy(res.data);`

You are assigning a reference to `data` property of res object instead of assigning the value of `data` property

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of angular JS two way data binding.
If you assign same data into two different purpose, best way is get a
copy

```
 $scope.foo = res.data;
 $scope.bar = angular.copy(res.data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **angular.copy** when assigning the value of object or array to another variable and that object value should not be changed.

Without **deep copy** or **using angular.cop**y, changing the value of object property will change the property value of all objects holding the same reference.

In your case **$scope.foo and $scope.bar holding the same reference**, so whenever you change the property of $scope.foo, $scope.bar is also getting updated. so you need to break the reference.

```
$scope.foo = angular.copy(res.data);
```