# AngularJS / JavaScript - Value is applied to all JSON in an Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Story:**
I created an array (`$scope.mainArray`) which will be presented in a `<table>` `<tr>` using `ng-repeat` like so:

```
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 2 |
+---+
| 3 |
+---+
```

Inside every each object is an array which is presented in `<td>` using `ng-repeat` like so:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| 1 | 1-1 | 1-2 | 1-3 |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| 2 | 2-1 | 2-2 | 2-3 |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| 3 | 3-1 | 3-2 | 3-3 |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

Each `<td>` is a boolean variable. If `true`, background color of `<td>` will turn into green. Otherwise, default background.

**Problem:**
Whenever I turn 1 `boolean` to `true`, all `<td>`'s in that column turns green. The code `$scope.mainArray[0].subArray[0].isGreen = true;` which is expected to turn cell `1-1` to green is making both `2-1` and `3-1` green.

**SSCCE:**
**Plunker:** https://plnkr.co/edit/9q3PMO?p=preview

**SO Snippet:**

```js
angular.module("App", [])

  .controller("Controller", function($scope) {
    var initSubArray = function() {
      var data = [{
        "value": 1,
        "label": 1,
        "isGreen": false
      }, {
        "value": 2,
        "label": 2,
        "isGreen": false
      }, {
        "value": 3,
        "label": 3,
        "isGreen": false
      }];

      return data;
    };

    var initMainArray = function() {
      var data = [{
        "value": 1,
        "label": 1
      }, {
        "value": 2,
        "label": 2
      }, {
        "value": 3,
        "label": 3
      }];

      return data;
    };

    var putSubArray = function() {
      var subArray = initSubArray();
      for (i = 0; i < $scope.mainArray.length; i++) {
        $scope.mainArray[i].subArray = subArray;
      }
    };

    $scope.init = function() {
      $scope.mainArray = initMainArray();
      putSubArray();
      $scope.mainArray[0].subArray[0].isGreen = true;
    };
  });
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: solid;
}

.green {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Controller" ng-init="init()">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="foo in mainArray">
      <td>
        {{foo.label}}
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat="bar in foo.subArray" ng-class="{'green' : bar.isGreen}">
        {{foo.label}}-{{bar.label}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are referencing your subArray object. That means that, when you change the subArray from an element inside mainArray, the original object is also being changed.

The subArray objects from the rest of the elements inside mainArray will be changed as well. To avoid this, I recommend you to use [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) inside your putSubArray function:

```
var putSubArray = function() {
    var subArray = initSubArray();
    for(i = 0; i < $scope.mainArray.length; i++ ) {
        $scope.mainArray[i].subArray = angular.copy(subArray);
    }
};
```

I also updated your [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/EGiAMeQfd3mnIyNCw9Wt?p=preview)

You can see a more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33044137/6255258)

Answer (score 6):

Just replace the below function, find code snippet. Additionally added `angular.copy` to avoid reference.
[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Holn63Ytt1auB6m445Zp?p=preview)

```
var putSubArray = function() {
    var subArray = initSubArray();
    for(i = 0; i < $scope.mainArray.length; i++ ) {
        $scope.mainArray[i].subArray = angular.copy(subArray);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you only have one subArray object. Which you then have three references too. When you make a change you are changing the subArray which all the rows are using.

You could fix this by changing this:

```
var putSubArray = function() {
    var subArray = initSubArray();
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.mainArray.length; i++) {
        $scope.mainArray[i].subArray = subArray;
    }
};
```

to

```
var putSubArray = function() {
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.mainArray.length; i++) {
        var subArray = initSubArray();
        $scope.mainArray[i].subArray = subArray;
    }
};
```

or a tidier variant on that